# Local rings vs local Banach algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\rad{rad}$Suppose $R$ is a ring and let $R^{-1}$ be the set of invertibles in $R$. Then we know there are examples of noncommutative rings st $R = R^{-} \cup \rad R$, where $\rad R$ is the Jacobson radical of $R$ - See chapter 7 of Lam's A first course in noncommutative rings. My question is this - are there examples of noncommutative Banach algebras $A$, such that $A = A^{-1} \cup \rad A$? And if so, can someone point me to a book that discusses these. I would expect it to be called a 'local' Banach algebra, but I don't seem to find that term in standard textbooks like Palmer's. Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a generic name for such Banach algebras, but I am away from my reference books right now so I cannot check. However, in Banach algebra world it is common not to require that algebras/rings have an identity element; so it is more likely that examples you are looking for are obtained by taking some B for which rad(B)=B and then adjoining an identity element. (There is a standard way of describing the Jacobson radical for not-necessarily-unital rings.)